# PHP-SOAP and null values, version dependent?

Tags: php, sql-server, soap

We have to migrate some website from a Debian server to another Redhat one. Every access to the database goes through webservices so we use SOAP to communicate with them (and the webservices call SQL Server stored procedures)

The problem is, there must be some differences between the servers (even though they're basically Apache2+PHP5) so that some calls fail in the new one.

One of them makes it very clear. It is a function to INSERT in a database, so we call the webservice through SoapClient with a few parameters. Sometimes these parameters might be empty. The problematic one is in fact usually empty.

Now when we call the webservice and @parameter is empty, it returns an error from the SQL Stored Procedure where it says that @parameter wasn't specified. Indeed if we set its value to 0 or 1 (it only fails with integers), it works. The really weird thing here is, it works perfect in our Debian setup, but it wont work in our new RedHat one.

Are there any SoapClient configuration parameters which could affect this? I have tried every option I could think of yet it still doesn't work (both webservices and SQL server are exactly the same! Only the Linux server changes!)

Thank you very much.

PS: To make things clearer, printing the SOAP-XML request that is sent, the old version one includes `<ns1:problematic_parameter/>` even if this parameter is empty, the new one doesn't include this tag. In both cases, it is called the same way `$client->Function(array('parameter' => $this->parameter [...] );`